# USB Port Speed Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, embedded-linux

How to programatically determine the usb port speed in embedded devices running the Linux kernel?

Comment: This either belongs on Server fault or you need to specify what language want to use.

Comment: Don't be silly: embedded devices don't have server admins (and neither are the people that run code on them "users", so it's not a superuser question either!).  It's clearly a question about embedded **development**, asking about programming for OS specific features.

Comment: All you need is lsusb -t

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can read `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb?/speed` - it'll give you the bus speed of the root hub(s) in Mbps: either 1.5, 12, 480, 5000 or 10000.  The first two indicate USB1 (low speed or full speed), the third USB2 and the fourth and fifth USB3.

Comment: and it says 5000 if it is USB3.  these are for root hubs.

Comment: Now it also says 10000 if you have USB3.1 Gen 2 (10 Gbps)

Comment: @AdrienJarthon - I see no `/sys/bus/usb`

Answer (score 1):

This rather depends on were the code that needs the information is running. If you want to modify a kernel USB device drivers behavior based on connection speed then the usb_device struct that passed to the driver by the USB subsystem contains a speed enumeration. If you want an application in user space to detect the devices connection speed then try walking the /sys/bus/usb tree you should be able to identify your USB device by checking the idProduct and idVendor entries. Once you have a match then the speed entry will give you what you need.
If you have multiple devices connected then you might need to figure a way to match USB id to specific device. Generally USB to device mappings vary on any hot plug support present whether the device supplies a serial number and the sub system that abstracts the functionality provided by the USB device.