# How to list USB port type with speed of connected device?

Tags: linux, usb, port, device

I'd like to have a command that outputs the USB port type (OHCI, UHCI, EHCI, XHCI, ...) and the device (if any) connected to, and the actual speed (HS, FS, SS, ...) for Linux. Preferably all in one line.

I want to find out quickly whether all devices are running at their highest possible speed.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: My question is not about using or configuring Linux.

Comment: Then what is it about? It's not about a program you've written, because you haven't posted any code.

Comment: Can't a programming question ask for a complete simple program (script) without having to start on by myself?
If you absolutely need some start, what about this script that lists the USB version number for each port (hopefully): `lsusb | sort -n | awk '$1 == "Bus" && $7 == "Linux" { print $2 ":" $4 " USB " $9 }'`

Comment: If you had put something like that in the question, I wouldn't have voted to close it. It looked to me like you were just looking for the name of a command that returns the information you want.

Comment: We don't write scripts for you here, we help you fix the ones you've written. But you have to post the script and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: OK, It seems the speeds can be found in `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/*/speed`. How could I correlate both, then?

Comment: Use a loop that sets a variable to each device name, then read `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/$name/speed`

Comment: If I had the solution, I wouldn't have to ask for help. I have this alternative that shows the USB hosts, type and maximum speed, but I still miss linking the devices to it: `for u in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*; do echo "$(<$u/busnum):$(<$u/devnum):$(cut -d' ' -f1 <$u/product) ($(<$u/speed)):"; done`

Comment: SO is not for getting other people to write code for you. It starts with you trying to come up with a solution yourself. If you can't get it working, post the code and we'll help you fix it. Put the code in the question, not comments, so you can format it nicely.

Answer (score -1):

I just discovered [USB Port Speed Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957589/usb-port-speed-linux) and the solution `lsusb -t` (which I didn't know before, because it's poorly documented). Here's an example output:

```
> lsusb -t
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
```

Also referred to by https://askubuntu.com/questions/598022/how-to-find-usb-hub-speed.